# Webrtc part crashes only on Release Build works fine on Debug build

Tags: java, android, webrtc

I am developing a Webrtc video chat application. It works fine on Debug build and doesn't crash but crashes on Release Build. My Webrtc version is

> implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.27771'

Whenever I call this function I get error

> ## Fatal error in:
>
> ../../../../usr/local/google/home/sakal/code/webrtc-aar-release/src/sdk/android/src/jni/jni_generator_helper.cc,
> line 59

And this is where it crashes,

```
    public void start() {

        if (Nammu.checkPermission(CAMERA)) {

            //NEW
            PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions initializationOptions =
                    PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(this)
                            //.setEnableVideoHwAcceleration(true)
                            .setEnableInternalTracer(true)
                            //.setFieldTrials("WebRTC-FlexFEC-03/Enabled/")
                            .createInitializationOptions();
            PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(initializationOptions);

           
            PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();
            DefaultVideoEncoderFactory defaultVideoEncoderFactory = new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(
                    rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(),  /* enableIntelVp8Encoder */true,  /* enableH264HighProfile */false);
            DefaultVideoDecoderFactory defaultVideoDecoderFactory = new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());

            
            //NEW
        peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
                .setOptions(options)
                .setVideoEncoderFactory(defaultVideoEncoderFactory)
                .setVideoDecoderFactory(defaultVideoDecoderFactory)
                .createPeerConnectionFactory();

            VideoCapturer videoCapturerAndroid;
            videoCapturerAndroid = createCameraCapturer(new Camera1Enumerator(false));

           
            audioConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
            videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
            sdpConstraints = new MediaConstraints();

            if (videoCapturerAndroid != null) {
                
                //NEW
            SurfaceTextureHelper surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("CaptureThread", rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
            videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(videoCapturerAndroid.isScreencast());
            videoCapturerAndroid.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, getApplicationContext(), videoSource.getCapturerObserver());

            }
            localVideoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("100", videoSource);

            //create an AudioSource instance
            audioSource = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioSource(audioConstraints);

            localAudioTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack("101", audioSource);
            localAudioTrack.setEnabled(true);
            localAudioTrack.setVolume(1);

            if (videoCapturerAndroid != null) {
                videoCapturerAndroid.startCapture(1024, 720, 30);
            }
            
            localVideoTrack.addSink(localVideoView);

            localVideoView.setMirror(true);
            remoteVideoView.setMirror(true);

            gotUserMedia = true;
            if (SignallingClient.getInstance().isInitiator) {
                onTryToStart();
            }
        }else {
            Nammu.askForPermission(this, CAMERA, permissionCameraCallback);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a progruad rules set up for your release build? If so, please post your proguard rules as well.

Comment: Thanks I have figured it out, it was progurd issue.

Comment: @SadmanSamee Please can you also post your solution as an Answer (instead of mixing it with your question) and then accept it as the approved answer? Thank you.

Comment: @SadmanSamee Do not include solution to question please (post a separate answer instead).

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem and the solution was

Add file `proguard-rules.pro` to the `app` folder

```
## WebRTC
-keep class com.cloudwebrtc.webrtc.** { *; }
-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; }
```

and in build.gradle, add below 2 properties to buildTypes -> release

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It was happening due to progurd issue. simply putting

```
    release {
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
```

Comment: hello,  the link above  says:
 By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /home/renyuzhuo/Android/Sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html